# TeamCity CommandLine batfile BuildStep has an issue with passed in env parameter

Tags: batch-file, cmd, build, teamcity

My commandline buildstep does not execute, because apparently the passed in parameter does not get accepted. I found the info that in order to pass variables into an bat file like this they need to be Environment Parameters in TeamCity in order to work, I tried that but it didnt work.

I am using TeamCity 2023.05.2 (build 129341) and I have a Unity project with a Unity buildstep which works without problems.
The second buildstep though is sadly the problematic part.

It's a command line step where I try to run a .bat file which should copy the build folder of the previous step to another folder.

This is the content of my .bat script:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "SourceFolder=%env.CHECKOUTDIR%\BTSCORE"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\Test"

echo SourceFolder is located at: %env.CHECKOUTDIR%
:: Find the last subfolder with relevant files based on commit number and datetime
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /ad /o-n "%SourceFolder%\*"') do (
    set "LastSubfolder=%%d"
    goto :FoundLast
)

:FoundLast
echo Last subfolder: !LastSubfolder!

:: Construct source and target paths
set "SourcePath=%SourceFolder%\!LastSubfolder!"
set "TargetPath=%DestinationFolder%\!LastSubfolder!"

if not exist "%SourcePath%" (
    echo Source folder does not exist!
    exit /b 1
)

:: Create the target directory if it does not exist
if not exist "%TargetPath%" (
    mkdir "%TargetPath%"
)

:: Copy the contents of the last subfolder to the target folder
xcopy /s /e /i "%SourcePath%\*" "%TargetPath%"

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Copy failed!
) else (
    echo Copy succeeded!
)

endlocal
```

Now when this steps runs I get a message that the Source Folder does not exist, the full log is:

```
Starting: G:\BatFiles\CopyBuild.bat G:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\Work\f1099063e78e73d4
18:09:12   in directory: G:\BatFiles
18:09:12   SourceFolder is located at:
18:09:12   Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
18:09:12   Last subfolder:
18:09:12   Source folder does not exist
18:09:12   Process exited with code 1
18:09:12   Process exited with code 1 (Step: Copy Files (Command Line))
18:09:12   Step Copy Files (Command Line) failed
```

I found the info that in order to pass variables into an bat file like this they need to be Environment Parameters in order to work,, but apparently the `%env.CHECKOUTDIR%` still cant be found.

I attached these two screenshots of my setup.

[image]

[image]

Where, and what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll call the two steps `firststep` and `secondstep`

If what you are doing is to execute

```
firststep
secondstep G:\TeamCity\BuildAgent\Work\f1099063e78e73d4
```

from the prompt, then in all probability, you are expecting `env.CHECKOUTDIR` to be established by `firststep`, and you are then assuming that `env.CHECKOUTDIR` can be used by `secondstep`.

If `firststep` contains a `setlocal` command, then any changes made to the environment after that `setlocal` will be backed out if an `endlocal` command is executed and the environment restored to its state when the `setlocal` was executed.

**Reaching end-of-file is an implicit `endlocal`**

Hence, you could simply invoke `secondstep` before `firststep` ends

firststep.bat

```
...
setlocal
...
secondstep
rem execution is now transferred to "secondstep" with the current environment intact
rem hence further commands will not be executed
```

Or you could run `secondstep` independently and provide `env.CHECKOUTDIR` as a parameter:

secondstep.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if not defined env.CHECKOUTDIR set "env.CHECKOUTDIR=%~1"

set "SourceFolder=%env.CHECKOUTDIR%\BTSCORE"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\Test"
...
```

Where `%~1` means "grab the first parameter provided to the batch, and remove any enclosing quotes" (If the parameter contains spaces, it should be quoted; if not, `%~1` is safe anyway)

Note that this deals with `env.CHECKOUTDIR` - there may be other variables that need to be dealt with - if that's the case, more info is required.

---

Another way to deal with this is to use (in the first batch)

```
...
endlocal&set "env.CHECKOUTDIR=%env.CHECKOUTDIR%"
```

which carries the change to `env.CHECKOUTDIR` "over the setlocal/endlocal bracket"

Oh - and BTW:

`!var!` implies that `var` is changing in a `for` loop and acquires the run-time value of the variable as it changes within the loop.

Since your code does not access a variable within a `for` loop, `%var%` is identical to `!var!`, so `!LastSubfolder!` can be `%LastSubfolder%` and in fact `delayedexpansion` is not required, which might assist with the use of exclamation marks in messages, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yeah what I was trying to do was basically the secondstep approach, just provide the env variable to the bat file. Apparently the issue was that %env.CHECKOUTDIR% does not exist and that I do actually need to use the syntax of %1

That being said I totally like the approach with

if not defined env.CHECKOUTDIR set "env.CHECKOUTDIR=%~1"

This helps and my issue is now solved, thanks a ton :)